# Integrate sin(x) w.r.t tan(x)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$ \int \sin x \ d(\tan x)$ 
While integrating a function, what all are the parameters that we can apply?

Comment: Do you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral ?

Answer (score 2):

Put $\tan x = t$ then $\sin x = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$, therefore the integral becomes $$\int \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^2}} dt $$ Now put $1+t^2 = p$, then $2t dt = dp$ hence the integral becomes on this sunstitution
$$\int\frac{dp}{2\sqrt p} = \sqrt p + C = \sqrt{1+t^2} +C = \sec x + C$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $d(tanx)=(tanx)'dx=sec^2(x)dx$ so you have that:
$$\int sin(x) d(tanx)=\int sin(x)sec^2(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $\tan x=p$ and you will see that $dp= sec^2 x \cdot dx$ thus integrating $\sin x$ w.r.t $\tan x$ is equivalent to integrating $\sec x \tan x$ w.r.t. $ x $which is easy enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is a change of variable $x$ to $u$.

$$\int \sin x \ d(\tan x)=\int \sin x  \sec^2 x \ dx = -\int \dfrac {du}{1+u^2}$$

when $$ u= \cos x $$